# Create and Edit drop down list's content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am wondering if I could have a drop down full with lists on a page and I can edit the text in that drop down and add another item. Basically it's up to the user what's the content of the drop down list. I am doing a project like a google form.

What I have tried at the moment is a standard drop down list. But what I'm trying to achieve is dynamically edit the values of the option and maybe I could add another item.

```
<div>
<select>
   <option value="editable1">Editable1</option>
   <option value="editable2">Editable2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: By user? If you want dynamically change values of dropdown you should at least tell from where will you take the content for them.

Comment: It's like this, if the user adds a drop down for their form, it's up to them to populate it.

Comment: Tell me if I'm right: so you have input, where user types text, then after click he adds this text to a dropdown?

Comment: There's a created drop down list, now the user should be able to edit the texts and add another item in the drop down list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
var i = 0;
$('#add').bind('click', function(e){
   var str = '<option value="'+i+'">';
   if ($('#add_text').val() != ''){
       str += $('#add_text').val() + '</option>';
           $('#select').append(str);
       $('#add_text').val('');
       i++;
   };
});

$('#edit').bind('click', function(e){
   $('#select :selected').text($('#add_text').val());
   if ($('#add_text').val() != ''){
      $('#select :selected').text($('#add_text').val());
   };
});
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zkh9L/1/

UPDATED: fiddle with popup input http://jsfiddle.net/Zkh9L/2/

UPDATE2: it looks like example from Vasani ,but you can add items http://jsfiddle.net/yUxr4/406/

Comment: Hi thanks for this but is it possible to not have a separate input text? I am curious if editing and adding a content could be done on the drop down list itself?

Comment: Not really, you can not type exactly into the option element, it could be made by popup input, but without it no.

Comment: Edited post, you can play with css, so it could look better, but the main point is there.

Comment: Thanks! But I would really want it like this, jsfiddle.net/yUxr4 . I wish there could be an option in the drop down to add another item.

Comment: Updated post. You can add items by selecting add and pressing enter

Comment: Thank you Good.luck! The only problem left is editing the existing items.

Comment: Actually you can edit, just select item and start typing

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks a lot! Can I know, how could I adjust it from pressing enter to just hovering outside of the drop down?

Comment: This fits to what I'm needing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

check the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eUWeR/1/)

you need to type text and click on add or edit.

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="editable1" id="editable1">Editable1</option>
    <option value="editable2" id="editable2">Editable2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="element_text" />
<input type="button" value="Add" id="add" />
<input type="button" value="Edit" id="edit" />
```

JS:

```
$( "#add" ).click(function() {
  var option_text = $("#element_text").val();
  var option_data = "<option value='"+option_text+"' id='"+option_text+"'>"+option_text+"</option>";
  $("#dropdown").append(option_data);
  $("#element_text").val("");
});
$( "#edit" ).click(function(){
  var option_text = $("#element_text").val();
  var option_data = "<option value='"+option_text+"' id='"+option_text+"'>"+option_text+"</option>";
  var id = $("#dropdown").val();
  var node = $("#"+id);
  node.remove(); 
  $("#dropdown").append(option_data);
  $("#element_text").val("");
});
```

Comment: Is it possible if there is no separate text box to edit or add an item? I am thinking if it could be edited right on the drop down list.

Comment: Thanks, but how could add an item here? When I edit an item, it changes the value but when I check again the drop down lists, it's not updated.

Comment: check the updated answer. and what do you mean by checking again? are you refreshing the page ? then you have to store it to html localstorage or at serverside

Comment: I'm trying this one out: jsfiddle.net/yUxr4 .If I edited the value 200 to 1000, and I then check the list of items, the value 200 is still there (it's not edited to 1000).

Comment: I have given this jsfiddle.net/yUxr4 only if you have requirement like that, you can try using that. That's not the actual solution.

Comment: Yes, I really like this kind of approach, but I can't seem to extend this to what I'm needing (i.e. adding and editing a list)